# Incorrectly writing array variable in while loop

Tags: php, while-loop

I want to store variables into a while loop for my mysqli:fetch() statement, problem is that I think I am writing the code incorrectly. Especially for the variable `$dataArraySession`, can anybody look at code below and state what is the correct way in writing the code below:

```
          $sessionquery = "
             SELECT SessionId, SessionDate, SessionTime, ModuleId
             FROM Session
             WHERE
             (ModuleId = ?)
             ORDER BY SessionDate, SessionTime 
            ";

$sessionqrystmt=$mysqli->prepare($sessionquery);
// You only need to call bind_param once
$sessionqrystmt->bind_param("s",$_POST['modulesDrop']);
// get result and assign variables (prefix with db)

$sessionqrystmt->execute(); 

$sessionqrystmt->bind_result($dbSessionId,$dbSessionDate,$dbSessionTime, $dbModuleId);

 $sessionqrystmt->store_result();

$sessionnum = $sessionqrystmt->num_rows();   

    $dataArraySession = array();

 while ( $sessionqrystmt->fetch() ) { 

 $dataArraySession[$dbModuleId]['Sessions'][$dbSessionId]['SessionDate'] = $dbSessoonDate['SessionTime'] = $dbSessionTime; 

}

foreach ($dataArraySession as $sessionId => $sessionData) {

   $sessionHTML = ""; 
   $sessionHTML .= '<select name="session" id="sessionsDrop">'.PHP_EOL;
   $sessionHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;           
   $sessionHTML .= "<option value='$sessionId'>" . $sessionId . " - " . $sessionData['SessionDate']. " - " . $sessionData['SessionTime'] ."</option>".PHP_EOL;        
   $sessionHTML .= '</select>';
        }


 if ($sessionnum > 0) {

 ?>

     <form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
     <p>Sessions: <?php echo $sessionHTML; ?><input id="sessionSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="sesionsubmit" /></p>      
    </form>       

<?php

}

else {
 echo "<p>Sorry, You have No Sessions under this Module</p>";
}

?>
```

Comment: `$dbSessionDate` is a value from query result, which in most cases would be a string or a number, so wouldn't `$dbSessionDate['SessionTime']` become invalid?

Comment: @Passerby It suppose to be read as `['SessionDate'] = $dbSessionDate ['SessionTime'] = $dbSessionTime; ` Im not sure if it becomes invalid because its a string, that's why I hope somebody knows for definite what is wrong with the while loop and the variables within

Comment: `$dbSessionDate` is bound from `$sessionqrystmt->bind_result()`, so it probably be a string or a number, thus `$dbSessionDate['SessionTime']` would be invalid. How exactly are you trying to store data?

Comment: @Passerby The data is going to be stored into a drop down menu, In the drop down menu it will display the session's id, time and date. I will update code so you can see what it looks like.

Comment: Please see my answer. But still, I don't know how are you trying to store your data **in PHP**, so I can only point our your mistake, but can not suggest a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several errors in your code:

1. After

   ```
   $dataArraySession = array();
   ```

   , `$dataArraySession` is an array, that's all. So assigning

   ```
   $dataArraySession[$dbModuleId]=something;
   ```

   is valid, but accessing/assigning

   ```
   $dataArraySession[$dbModuleId]["Sesssions"]
   ```

   (in your while-loop) is invalid, because `$dataArraySession[$dbModuleId]` is still undefined;
2. `$dbSessionDate` is a bound value from `$sessionqrystmt->bind_result()`, so it would probably be a string or a number, so

   ```
   ... = $dbSessionDate['SessionTime'] = ...
   ```

   is invalid, because it's just a string, not an array;
3. In your output loop, you're also echoing invalid variables.

   In your while-loop, `$dataArraySession` is defined as

   ```
   array(
     [module_id]s => array(
       'Sessions' => array (
         [session_id]s => array (
           'SessionDate' => _value_
         )
       )
     )
   )
   ```

   So with

   ```
   foreach ($dataArraySession as $sessionId => $sessionData)
   ```

   ,`$sessionData` is only at the level of `'Sessions' => array (...`, thus `$sessionData` has only one key, `'Sessions'`, and both `$sessionData['sessionDate']` and `$sessionData['sessionTime']` are invalid.

Comment: Hi, just saw your comment, the data is stored in a database so I am using php to retrievie it from the datbase

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you made a typo:

```
$dbSesisonDate['SessionTime']
     ^^^
```

Should also throw an `undefined variable` error if you have `display_errors` on in your development environment.

Comment: Haha, sorry bout that, I realised I did the type straight after I posted the question. Am I using the `=` signs incorrectly because it does not fetch results from the fetch statement in the while loop